# Convex combinatorial affine projection symbol algorithm

Tags: filter

Schematic diagram of the filter principle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ98M.png)

The output of the overall algorithm can be expressed as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8QoV.png)

The updated formula is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm9pU.png)

The combination factors are indirectly updated with the Sigmoidal function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF0Ft.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chjky.png)

a ranges from minus 4 to 4

I programmed through Matlab, but the combination factor λ remained unchanged at 0.5.

Would you please see what went wrong? How do I modify it?

```html
clc;
clear all
close all
N = 10000;                      
L = 120;                         
pi = 3.14;                       
M = 4;                           
varepsilon = 0.01;               
theta = 0;                      

k = 1:L;
h = 1./k.*exp(-(k-L/2).^2/8000).*sin(pi*(k-1)/6);

num = [1];
den = [1,-0.9];
x = filter(num,den,randn(1,N));

Xap1= zeros(M,L);
Xap2= zeros(M,L);
e=zeros(N,M);
e1 = zeros(N,M);
e2 = zeros(N,M);
e3 = zeros(N,M);
e4 = zeros(N,M);
he=zeros(N,L);
he1= zeros(N,L);
he2 = zeros(N,L);
he3 = zeros(N,L);
he4 = zeros(N,L);
ky=zeros(N,1);
ad=zeros(N,1);
ad(124)=-0.01;

mu1=0.1;
mu2=0.005;
for k1 = L+M:N
    for i = 1:L
        Xap1(:,i) = x(k1+1-i:-1:k1+2-M-i)';
    end
    g = (1-theta)/(2*L)+(1+theta)*abs(he1(k1,:))/(2*norm(he1(k1,:),1)+varepsilon);
    G = diag(g);
    e1(k1,:) = (Xap1*h'-Xap1*he1(k1,:)')';
    e2(k1,:) = (Xap1*h'-Xap1*he2(k1,:)')';
    ky(k1)=1/(1+exp(-0.0001*ad(k1)));
    ad(k1+1)=ad(k1)+2000*ky(k1)*(1-ky(k1))*sign(e(k1,:))*(Xap1*he1(k1,:)'-Xap1*he2(k1,:)');
 
    %     if ad(k1+1)<-4
    %         ad(k1+1)=-4;
    %     end
    %     if ad(k1+1)>4
    %         ad(k1+1)=4;
    %     end
    e(k1,:)=ky(k1)*e1(k1,:)+(1-ky(k1))*e2(k1,:);
    he1(k1+1,:) = he1(k1,:)+mu1*sign(e(k1,:))*Xap1*G/(sqrt(sign(e(k1,:))*Xap1*G*Xap1'*sign(e(k1,:)')));
    %     if (ad(k1)==4)
    %         he2(k1+1,:) = 0.9*he2(k1,:)+(1-0.9)*he1(k1,:)+mu2*sign(e(k1,:))*Xap1*G/(sqrt(sign(e(k1,:))*Xap1*G*Xap1'*sign(e(k1,:)')));
    %     else
    he2(k1+1,:) = he2(k1,:)+mu2*sign(e(k1,:))*Xap1*G/(sqrt(sign(e(k1,:))*Xap1*G*Xap1'*sign(e(k1,:)')));
    %     end
    he(k1,:)=ky(k1)*he2(k1,:)+(1-ky(k1))*he1(k1,:);
    %     He(k1,:)=he(k1,:);
    
    k1
end
for k2 = L+M:N
    for i = 1:L
        Xap1(:,i) = x(k2+1-i:-1:k2+2-M-i)';
    end
    g = (1-theta)/(2*L)+(1+theta)*abs(he3(k2,:))/(2*norm(he3(k2,:),1)+varepsilon);
    G = diag(g);
    e3(k2,:) = (Xap1*h'-Xap1*he3(k2,:)')';
    he3(k2+1,:) = he3(k2,:)+mu1*sign(e3(k2,:))*Xap1*G/(sqrt(sign(e3(k2,:))*Xap1*G*Xap1'*sign(e3(k2,:)')));
    %     He1(k2,:)=he3(k2,:);
    k2
end
for k3 = L+M:N
    for i = 1:L
        Xap1(:,i) = x(k3+1-i:-1:k3+2-M-i)';
    end
    g = (1-theta)/(2*L)+(1+theta)*abs(he4(k3,:))/(2*norm(he4(k3,:),1)+varepsilon);
    G = diag(g);
    e4(k3,:) = (Xap1*h'-Xap1*he4(k3,:)')';
    he4(k3+1,:) = he4(k3,:)+mu2*sign(e4(k3,:))*Xap1*G/(sqrt(sign(e4(k3,:))*Xap1*G*Xap1'*sign(e4(k3,:)')));
    %     He2(k3,:)=he4(k3,:);
    k3
end
%%
figure(5)
Misalign_CAPSA = 10*log10(sum((he-h).^2,2)/sum(h.^2));
Misalign_APSA1 = 10*log10(sum((he3-h).^2,2)/sum(h.^2));
Misalign_APSA2 = 10*log10(sum((he4-h).^2,2)/sum(h.^2));
plot(1:length(x),Misalign_CAPSA,1:length(x)+1,Misalign_APSA1,1:length(x)+1,Misalign_APSA2)
legend('CIPAPSA','APSA1','APSA2')
```